"Unable to Infer Schema for Parquet File in Spark: AnalysisException"
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to read a Parquet file using Spark's spark.read.parquet() function. Here's the code snippet I'm using:
spark.read.parquet(path='dbfs:/FileStore/parquet_data')
However, it's throwing the following error:
AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.
I've searched through the documentation and various forums but haven't found a clear solution. Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this error? If manual specification of the schema is required, what's the best approach to do so in Spark?

Spark throws this error when the specified directory empty. Check if that directory contains parquet files or not.

below code works fine :
df = spark.read.format('parquet') 
.option("inferSchema", 'false') 
.option("header", 'false') 
.option("sep", ',') 
.load('dbfs:/FileStore/Flights_1m.parquet')
